# Bootstrap 4 media horizontal center

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The question is in the title. How I can center a media horizontal?

My media:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="media">
                <img class="mr-3" src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Trexon</h5>
                    <p>LOL</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The {{ $user->avatar }} is from Laravel.

[image]

Comment: Does media have a known width?

Comment: Yes the width from the container. 1110px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the column a flexbox and set its `justify-content: center;`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
            <div class="media">
                <img class="mr-3" src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Trexon</h5>
                    <p>LOL</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** You don't need to specify all breakpoints' version of `col-12`. You only need the smallest one, if all are taking up 12 columns.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. One question. Do I need a row if I use only one `col`?
_Note: You don't need to specify all breakpoints' version of col-12. You only need the smallest one, if all are taking up 12 columns._ **Aight**

Comment: @Trexon: nope. You even don't need the `row` as well as `col-12` class if you intend to put up a `<div>` that ALWAYS takes up all available width of the container. You only need the `row` and different versions of `col-12` if you intend to change the width based on breakpoints. But `row` and `col-*` classes have to be used together - whenever there is a row, there must be columns.

Comment: Aight. Thank You! :) And im gonna learn flexbox! :D

Comment: @Trexon: this is a good start: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
            <div class="media justify-content-center">
                <img class="mr-3" src="{{ $user->avatar }}" alt="Avatar">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">Trexon</h5>
                    <p>LOL</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try this adding the class justify-content-center, if it doesnot work add the class text-center. if it does not work then use flexbox. [learn-flex-box](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-css-flexbox-in-5-minutes-b941f0affc34)